# Managing existing Split Screens in ConEmu

Tags: conemu

I can happily create the split screens but I want to take it a bit further and looking at docs and code could not see anything obvious so asking in case I missed it.

1. Once I have a split screen running how can I reference it in the future given the tabs with the split could be one of many and at any location in the tabs collection. If I could pull the current tab number out as a property then I could do the TxSy assuming y is a constant in my configuration.
2. How can I determine the tab/split I am running in. If a tab opens a split and a command runs how can I pull the split number under that tab number as properties.

If I can get these properties from the running script I think I am ok at directing commands to the other tabs/splits using the guimacro commands just having issues consistently getting the numbers right. Would be nice if I could name the tabs and splits and reference them from the names and not the numbers to be more deterministic.